# Will there be a careers.serverfault.com?

Tags: support, careers

I answer questions both on Serverfault & Stackoverflow, although my user ranking is much higher on serverfault.com.

If I sign up for careers.stackoverflow.com as a SQL Server DBA, will this be worthwhile? Or will I have to fork out more money for careers.serverfault to associate my SF user account if/when that happens?

Maybe being a SQL Server DBA is one of these gray areas in IT that is a bit cross functional where some questions are relevant for me on both sites, so I'm the gap case.

**EDIT: Yes! I'm signing up for vapourware**

Comment: +1 for some SF lovin' ;)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24915/associate-accounts-with-other-so-family-sites

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will definitely be able to associate your Super User and Server Fault accounts with your Stack Overflow CV, if you want to.

In fact they are already associated (including Meta), but we suppress display of anything except the SO account right now.

We aren't entirely sure if there will be a careers.serverfault.com and careers.superuser.com at the moment. **Personally, I think it makes more sense to have a single careers site everyone can go to, rather than two or three.** There's no benefit to "splitting" the conversation when it comes to employment and getting a critical mass of employers and CVs.

Clarification: if we do end up having careers.serverfault.com and careers.superuser.com (which I deem unlikely at this point) there will be NO additional charge to list your CV all three places. I can guarantee that.

Comment: I just edited my post, the comment was getting to complicated

Comment: I agree that having seperate sites doesn't make a great deal of sense, but I'd like to be able to have my Server Fault account be the prominant one, as thats where my skills really lie. It would also be good if employers looking for sysadmins could search for those with a high rep on SF rather than SO

Comment: if that's the case, then you got my $30... now where are my free serverfault stickers dammit! i keep checking my mailbox daily, but still nothing

Comment: My 2 cents as a SF users...it get's annoying when the things done on the trilogy of sites center around SO and ignore the other communities. :)

Comment: It would be really awesome to unsuppress the display of Serverfault badges on careers. I've got 101 on SO and 10K on SF.

Comment: Yep, would be great, i've got 1k on SO and 12K on SF

Comment: So @Jeff any news?

Comment: I would like to know too. While the splitting the conversation has some weight to it, having a separate place for sysadmin jobs would maybe bring more jobs to it. Currently there are not many on careers.SO

Answer (score 3):

According to the comment responses from Jarrod on [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24897/stackoverflow-careers) ( last response on the page) there will eb SF and SU versions coming.

Comment: will the $29 cover me for those sites too? or will i have to fork out more cash?

Comment: You mean people are actually looking for superusers?

Comment: How about careers.meta.stackoverflow.com?  Jobs for people who are good at talking about stuff?

Comment: @Ivo Who do you want providing tech support?

Comment: I'd like to think I'm doing more than tech support on SU, although that's probably exactly what I'm doing :(

Answer (score 2):

Completely agree that one site would be better than a multitude, but as a SuperUser-user I have a hard time filling in the questions for the CV.

Favorite technology: Windows-7? Plus my work experience isn't a measure for my SuperUser activity, even though I do handle some of the computer related support questions at work. Also in my case, my education isn't computer science related AT ALL, so it doesn't really make sense to fill it in.

I understand if they first want to see how it goes and then create spin-off CVs that are more directed to other careers, just want to know if I should take the discount 'while I can' ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If it's any comfort, it's already implemented in the tooltip for the 'Associate accounts' tab :)